# I get error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I get an error `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`  In sql developer shows there is syntax error`syntax error expected: (`  in this line

> BUDGET_MANAGEMENT_SCENARIO.property_id =
>   u.property_id,BUDGET_MANAGEMENT_SCENARIO.agency_id = u.agency_id

Here is my sql statement

```
 SELECT
   PROPERTY_NAME, AGENCY_NAME, ADVERTISER_NAME,
   BUYING_AE_NAME, CLIENT_AE_NAME 
 FROM "BUDGET_MANAGEMENT_SCENARIO"
 WHERE "BUDGET_MANAGEMENT_SCENARIO"."PROPERTY_ID" = 2 AND
       "BUDGET_MANAGEMENT_SCENARIO"."QUARTER_ID" IN (17, 18, 19, 20) AND
       ((BUDGET_MANAGEMENT_SCENARIO.property_id =
         u.property_id,BUDGET_MANAGEMENT_SCENARIO.agency_id = u.agency_id) # ERROR
       IN (SELECT
             property_id, agency_id
           FROM "PACING_BUDGET_DETAIL"
           WHERE (bae_app_user_id = 1 OR  pae_app_user_id = 1 OR
                 cae_app_user_id = 1)
        UNION
           SELECT property_id, agency_id
           FROM  "USER_ASSIGNMENT"
           WHERE "USER_ASSIGNMENT"."APP_USER_ID" = 1 AND
                 "USER_ASSIGNMENT"."PACING_BUDGET" = 1) u);
```

Comment: you might want to format the statement properly - that usually helps in finding errors like that. At first glance: `UNIONSELECT`?

Comment: is this an oracle query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct select is:

```
SELECT PROPERTY_NAME, AGENCY_NAME, ADVERTISER_NAME,BUYING_AE_NAME,CLIENT_AE_NAME 
FROM "BUDGET_MANAGEMENT_SCENARIO"
WHERE "BUDGET_MANAGEMENT_SCENARIO"."PROPERTY_ID" = 2 AND
  "BUDGET_MANAGEMENT_SCENARIO"."QUARTER_ID" IN (17, 18, 19, 20) AND
  ( BUDGET_MANAGEMENT_SCENARIO.property_id, BUDGET_MANAGEMENT_SCENARIO.agency_id)
     IN (SELECT   property_id, agency_id FROM "PACING_BUDGET_DETAIL" WHERE (bae_app_user_id = 1 OR  pae_app_user_id = 1 OR cae_app_user_id = 1)UNION SELECT property_id, agency_id FROM  "USER_ASSIGNMENT" WHERE "USER_ASSIGNMENT"."APP_USER_ID" = 1 AND  "USER_ASSIGNMENT"."PACING_BUDGET" = 1) u);
```

Problem was in (x =x1,y=y1) in (SELECT x1,y1) it should be: (x,y) in (SELECT x1,y1) IT matches exact rows with x,y that are in (x1,y1)

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me `ORA-00920: invalid relational operator`

Comment: sorry, left one propperty, it should be OK now

Comment: Still i get invalid relational operator..in sql developer console the syntax error is highlited as `expected: ORDER, GROUP` at this position  `UNIONSELECT`

Comment: Turns out i just needed space between UNION and SELECT..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following isn't valid SQL:

```
(BUDGET_MANAGEMENT_SCENARIO.property_id = u.property_id,BUDGET_MANAGEMENT_SCENARIO.agency_id = u.agency_id)
IN (SELECT ...
```

I'm not exactly sure what you're attempting to do, but you cannot compare columns and use the result of that comparison in an `IN (...)` clause.

Comment: @Mr.Liama - Thanks, for pointing out, so what would be the right way ?

Comment: @sparks - I have no idea what you were trying to accomplish with that logic, so I don't know how to fix it.  Could you explain what you *wanted* it to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is something missing or maybe there is some spurious extra stuff in this part:

```
(BUDGET_MANAGEMENT_SCENARIO.property_id =
     u.property_id,BUDGET_MANAGEMENT_SCENARIO.agency_id = u.agency_id)
```

Perhaps you meant to add something to it so it is like this?:

```
(BUDGET_MANAGEMENT_SCENARIO.property_id = u.property_id  AND
     u.property_id,BUDGET_MANAGEMENT_SCENARIO.agency_id = u.agency_id)
```

Comment: what Shin suggested is what i want but  i just i need to get rid of those errors